# Programmatically drawn UIView tags (or something alike)

Tags: objective-c

I'm drawing a view that contains an xib, multiple times (same uiview) and then update the outlets each time it gets drawn displaying an nsmutablearray with different strings on the outlets

Clicking the view opens a viewcontroller that should be displaying the data from the view (+more), this works perfectly fine except it doesn't know which index of the array it's supposed to be displaying.

I'm trying to figure out a way to manage them in a way that I can see which view is being pressed so I can pass that 'id' onto the new vc (something to uniquely identify the view even though it's the same view being drawn)

Here's how the view is being drawn multiple times

```
- (void) populateUpcoming:(int)events {
[self resetVariables];
upcomingEventsCenterPos = self.view.frame.size.width / 2 - 159;
for (int i = 0; i < events; i++) {
    upcomingEventsY2 = 175 * upcomingEvents2;
    UIView *firstViewUIView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UpcomingEventFull" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
    [_scrollView addSubview:firstViewUIView];
    CGRect frame = firstViewUIView.frame;
    frame.origin.y = 9 + upcomingEventsY2;
    frame.origin.x = upcomingEventsCenterPos + upcomingEventsX2;
    firstViewUIView.frame= frame;
    upcomingEvents2++;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                            action:@selector(tapUpcomingEvent:)];
    [firstViewUIView addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
}
[self setupScroll];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `UITableView` and custom `UITableViewCell` for this purpose. On click of "Add More", add one entry to NSMutableArray and just reload tableview.
And no need to manage index separately, you can get it directly by `indexPath.row`

Also you don't need to manage scroll view size as tableview automatically adjust is content height according to row.

If you are using same kind of view,then go with this approach, as its easy and will save your time.

Comment: it could (and probably should) be done this way, yes, I'm not looking to rewrite the entirety of the application tho, plus I'm doing this both horizontally and vertically so I need a solution for the code I'm working with unfortunately (if possible)